# Bootstrap javascript for a webpage

Tags: jquery

what is Bootstrap java Script and how and where it is used

I have searched Google but could not get what it is exactly.
what I could find on internet is , it is a set of java scripts ,CSS and images

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: there's just sooo much information out there on bootstrap. Make sure you know the fundamentals of HTML,CSS,and JavaScript (or just HTML and CSS at least) - with those there's no reason why bootstrap will be a mystery. If you are lacking in those areas you are probably better off leaving bootstrap and focusing on those first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, that is the definition of the Bootstap, and your question really just wants the answer (definition) of the term Bootstrap, so a simple google for `What is Bootstrap` would yield the same answer. It really is a set of HTML, CSS, JS, sometimes Images, but that's just to make sure that there UI gets perfectly fit.

> a technique of loading a program into a computer by means of a few initial instructions that enable the introduction of the rest of the program from an input device.

This was the definition from Google. Which means, that the bootstrap (in simple language for you..) is a plugin that you add to your website, so that you can write less, get more!

And not just simple HTML or CSS, it contains alot more content such as built-in classes or ids for buttons and elements. Built-in event handlers, so you have to write just a few words to handle all the events such as `click` instead of going back to the JS Dom and writing it from scratch.

For example Twitter Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

You can get the source code from the above link, and use it for your website. They have a documentation for it, so I won't bother confusing you, you can read it there! :)